# change regex to validate that at least 2 of the characters are alpha

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z'-\d]+$/
```

I would like to change it to validate that at least 2 of the characters are alpha:

This passes:

/^[a-zA-Z'-\d]+$/.test('-\'')

But I would like it fail unless it is something like:

```
/^[a-zA-Z'-\d]+$/.test('ab-\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/^(?:[\d'-]*[a-zA-Z]){2}[a-zA-Z\d'-]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhvIKz/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[\d'-]*[a-zA-Z]){2}`  - 2 sequences of:

  - `[\d'-]*` - 0+ chars that are digits, `-` or `'`
  - `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z\d'-]*` - 0+ chars that are alphanumeric, `'` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

With a case insensitive modifier, the pattern can be shortened a bit:

```
/^(?:[\d'-]*[a-z]){2}[a-z\d'-]*$/i
```